# How do I parse an HTML string and select in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ajax call that returns a long HTML string.  What I'd like to do is collect all the innerText of the button tags.  Can this be achieved using angular without jQuery?

Ajax response:

```
<div><div><button>Player 1</button><span></span><h1></h1><button>Player2</button></div></div> etc.. 
//Id like to have an array of ['Player1','Player2']
```

Comment: could you just use  regular expression to get everything between the button. 
you can use plain old java script (document.getElementByTagName) but you will need to make sure your html you have got from your ajax call is rendered to the DOM before you can search on it

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using vanilla JavaScript using [Dom Parser](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#apis-for-parsing-and-serializing-dom).

```
function getButtonText(htmlString) {
    // create a document fragment from the html string
    let documentFragment = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

    // retrieve a list of buttons from the fragment
    let buttons = documentFragment.getElementsByTagName('button');

    // convert and return the buttons from DOMElements to Text
    return Array.from(buttons).map(button => button.innerText);
}
```

If the browsers you are targeting do not support [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) you can change the last line to a simple for loop.